# ffmpeg getting filter logs

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I've used ffmpeg libavfilter/af_silencedetect.c im my program and it works like a charm.

This filter logs some information about duration of silence in output as follows:

```
[silencedetect @ 0x2a894c0] silence_start: 0
[silencedetect @ 0x2a894c0] silence_end: 1.61725 | silence_duration: 1.61725
[silencedetect @ 0x2a894c0] silence_start: 3.19175
[silencedetect @ 0x2a894c0] silence_end: 4.70413 | silence_duration: 1.51238
```

But I need to get these durations in my program. How can I get these values as a variable in my program. It's worth to note that because of modularity I don't wanna make changes in af_silencedetect.c file.

Thanks

Comment: Parse the log file into variables. The format looks pretty simple.

Comment: You usually pass a SilenceDetectContext to the functions in af_silencdetect, from which you can read the start and duration of silence periods after analyzing the samples.

Comment: thanks @Ctx, But I used `init_filters(const char *filters_descr)` and `static const char *filter_descr = "silencedetect=n=-10dB:d=1";`, so I don't acces `SilenceDetectContext` in my program. Is there any other method to call filters in my program?

Comment: The filters writes metadata keys with names like `lavfi.silence_start`. Once you have the processed AVFrame, access them using `av_dict_get`

Comment: @Gyan, thanks for your contribution. Is there any similar metadata keys for `volumedetect` filter?

Comment: Not implemented. You can use astats filter and check for `lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Gyan said you can use *metadata keys* something like **lavfi.silence_start**, **lavfi.silence_end** and **lavfi.silence_duration**. These values are set with **av_dict_set** and also, you set other metadata keys.

Then in your program you utilize **av_dict_get** to obtain these values. With this method you can separate your logic from ffmpeg codes.

Answer (score -1):

```
initialize astats audio filter as
```

AVFilter *astats =avfilter_get_by_name("astats");

`snprintf(strbuf, sizeof(strbuf),"reset=1:metadata=1");`
`avfilter_graph_create_filter(&astats_ctx, astats,NULL, strbuf, NULL, filtergraph);`

then from filtered audio frame  get the rms level  as

`AVDictionaryEntry *e = NULL;`
`while(e = av_dict_get(filter_frame>metadata,"lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level", e,AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX))`
`{`
printf("%s:%s\n", e->key, e->value);
}

Comment: You should format the code better and insert an explanation of what it does, instead of simply dumping it.